# Issue with Visual Studio not seeing arduino boards

Tags: arduino-uno

Below is a screenshot. I used Visual Studio with the Visual Micro [arduino extension] a few months back. I switched computers and installed Visual Studio on the new one but for some reason after Visual Micro has been installed its not seeing any of the boards. In the visua lMicro explorer it doesnt have an option for the board manager. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an Arduino question. To me, it seems more a problem with the software. Anyway, have you installed the Arduino drivers? If yes, then I only can suggest a restart of your computer and if that doesn't work a clean install of all the relevant software. That is under the assumption that your computer (in device manager) is able to detect the Arduinos, but visual studio is not.

Comment: The arduino ide has no problem uploading to the board. I reinstalled visual studio and the visual micro extension and still the same issue. I'm using the arduino ide right now but i prefer visual studio

Comment: Sorry I missed this. Did you correct the path to the Arduino IDE or version? Or was this a windows store version of Arduino which is only recently supported? Hope you got it sorted. There is a forum at visualmicro.com if anyone needs help.